Errormessage for FuncAnimation in Jupyter
I have just written this code for the last project in school.
It works in Visual Studio, but when running the code there I get this errormessage (even though the program runs fine).
c:\main.py:193: UserWarning: frames=None which we can infer the length of, did not pass an explicit *save_count* and passed cache_frame_data=True.  To avoid a possibly unbounded cache, frame data caching has been disabled. To suppress this warning either pass `cache_frame_data=False` or `save_count=MAX_FRAMES`.
  ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), func=animate, fargs=([velocity*math.cos(angle), velocity*math.sin(angle)],), interval=UPDRATE)

However, I guess that I have to present the code in Jupyter. When I copy my code there, the program doesn't run at all. I get the error message:
/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py:872: UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you output the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`.
  warnings.warn(

I have no idea how to interpret this errormessage. Can you please explain a solution?
Part of code attached:
def animate(i, velocities):
    # Do things
    
def main():
    # Declare and call the animation function
    ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), func=animate, fargs=([velocity*math.cos(angle), velocity*math.sin(angle)],), interval=UPDRATE)
    plt.show()
    
main()


Please edit your post and make things accurate or remove unrelated, spurious issues. For example, you start with: "It works in Vistual Studio, but when running the code there I get this errormessage (even though the program runs fine)." Yes, it runs fine because it clearly states it is not an error, it is a warning. Treat it as such. On to your actual issue, you are having a back and forth with Francisco because you didn't share a minimal reproducible example as you are asked. Please read How do I ask a good question?, especially the section ...

 under 'Help others reproduce the problem'. Also include in your post exactly what version and flavor of Jupyter you are using. The older versions have very different needs than the newer versions and so it is imperative to avoid more going back and forth.

You can try to add 'cache_frame_data=False' to your 'ani':
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), func=animate, fargs=([velocitymath.cos(angle), velocitymath.sin(angle)],), interval=UPDRATE , cache_frame_data=False)

I have tried that already, none of the changes I have made solved my problem. I would really appreciate any advices how to get this to work, I have the presentation tomorrow.

Your animation object ani is being garbage collected because it's defined inside main(), which means that it doesn't persist after the function exits, which should be causing the error. I think moving ani to a global scope (putting it outside any functions) should be enough to solve the issue.
For example:
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import HTML
import math

def animate(i, velocities):
    # Your animation code here
    pass;

velocity = 10;
angle = math.radians(45);
UPDRATE = 100;

# Create the animation object in global scope!
ani = FuncAnimation(
    plt.gcf(),
    func=animate,
    fargs=([velocity * math.cos(angle), velocity * math.sin(angle)],),
    interval=UPDRATE);

# Display the animation in Jupyter Notebook
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())


Unfortunately, it does not solve my problem. I get this error code:
/tmp/ipykernel_253/612730780.py:202: UserWarning: frames=None which we can infer the length of, did not pass an explicit save_count and passed cache_frame_data=True.  To avoid a possibly unbounded cache, frame data caching has been disabled. To suppress this warning either pass cache_frame_data=False or save_count=MAX_FRAMES.
ani = FuncAnimation(

That's a different issue, adding a constant MAX_FRAMES (set it to 100 for example) and passing the parameters frames=MAX_FRAMES and cache_frame_data=False to FuncAnimation() should work

Thanks for taking your time!
That doesn't solve my problem either. I have passed those arguments, but it doesn't behave as it does in VSC at all. I don't know if there's any difference between that I run the program in VSC with CTRL+F5, and in Jupyter i start by press SHIFT+ENTER. I am not sure what the difference is tbh.
https://ibb.co/k861m3k and
https://ibb.co/mSWYW9v
